# How to display long NSString in 1 row of a section in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

This is my second project in iOS development and I am trying to display an itinerary for a hackathon in a UITableView object. I'm storing the the list of activities and their associated times in one NSString variable named 'events' and then trying to display it with 'cell.textLabel.text = schedule.events' and it only displayed the first activity in the events variable. I then tried increasing the the height of the row but that didn't solve my problem either. Am I approaching this wrong?

I starting thinking thinking that events should be an NSArray holding string literals of each activity but then couldn't figure out how to display each string literal in that array as an individual row of the three sections: Friday, Saturday, and Sunday. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

[Screenshot of iOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pncRs.png)

Here is my code for the ViewController with UITableView

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "Weekend.h"

@interface ScheduleViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tablesView;


@end

#import "ScheduleViewController.h"

@interface ScheduleViewController ()

@end

@implementation ScheduleViewController {

    NSArray *allWeekendDays;
    NSArray *allEvents;
}

@synthesize tablesView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Set up schedule for friday
    Weekend *friday = [[Weekend alloc] init];
    friday.day = @"Friday, March 20th\n";
    friday.events = @"9:00 PM       Check-In\n"
                     "11:00 PM      Opening Ceremony\n"
                     "11:59 PM      Begin Hacks";

    //Set up schedule for saturday
    Weekend *saturday = [[Weekend alloc] init];
    saturday.day = @"Saturday, March 21st";
    saturday.events = @"2:00 AM     Snack Time\n"
                       "8:00 AM     Breakast\n"
                       "1:00 PM     Lunch\n"
                       "7:30 PM     Dinner\n"
                       "10:00 PM    Nerf-Gun Wars";

    //Set up schedule for sunday
    Weekend *sunday = [[Weekend alloc] init];
    sunday.day = @"Sunday, March 22nd";
    sunday.events = @"2:00 AM       Snack Time\n"
                     "6:30 AM       Breaskfast\n"
                     "7:30 AM       End Hacks\n"
                     "8:00 AM       Expo 1\n"
                     "9:00 AM       Expo 2\n"
                     "10:00 AM      Closing Ceremony";

    allWeekendDays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:friday, saturday, sunday, nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark Table View Data Source Method
/*Ask about how to set style of table to grouped programmatically
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect style:(UITableViewStyle)style {

    return self.tablesView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
}
*/

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //Defines how many sections in my table
    return [allWeekendDays count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Defines how many rows will be in each section
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Defines how each individual cell will loook like

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"WeekendCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    //Changed indexPath.row to indexPath.section
    Weekend *schedule = [allWeekendDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = schedule.events;

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Define the header of each section to be the week day
    Weekend *schedule = [allWeekendDays objectAtIndex:section];

    return schedule.day;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 100.0;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to set `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines` to 0;
This way you get an auto-growing UILabel.

---

But in my opinion I would use one one cell per event, not day. You already grouped the individual days, so that will work nicely!

To do that, use events as an array that contains multiple strings. 
Here are some small code changes:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Defines how many rows will be in each section
    return [[allWeekendDays[section] events] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Defines how each individual cell will loook like

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"WeekendCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    //Changed indexPath.row to indexPath.section
    Weekend *schedule = [allWeekendDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = schedule.events[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

...
//Set up schedule for sunday
Weekend *sunday = [[Weekend alloc] init];
sunday.day = @"Sunday, March 22nd";
sunday.events = @["2:00 AM       Snack Time\n",
                 "6:30 AM       Breaskfast\n",
                 "7:30 AM       End Hacks\n",
                 "8:00 AM       Expo 1\n",
                 "9:00 AM       Expo 2\n",
                 "10:00 AM      Closing Ceremony"];
```

Comment: Is there more code I need to add to enable scrolling?

Comment: I put self.tableView.bounces = YES; in my viewDidLoad

Comment: As UITableView is a subview of UIScrollView, your table view should scroll by default

Comment: Thank you for the above code, that's exactly what I was thinking with my second thought! It's not letting me scroll through my table though in the iOS simulator

Comment: You can't scroll as you would in an OS X app. Try to drag your mouse